# How to read column one by one in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, anaconda

I have read file from URL as follows :

```
    url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data"

    names = ['sepal length', 'sepal width', 'petal length', 'petal width',  'class']

    data = pd.read_csv(url, names=names)

    print(data.shape)

    print(data)
```

Now, I want to read one column and do some processing (may be min, max, or std dev, r score etc) and then again read another column and do some processing.

Is there any way to do it in scikit learn/pandas/python?

Comment: df["column_name"] will get you the elements in the column alone. You can then change its type to list and do any processing. There are some functions in pandas which does basic processing for columns like sorting, finding max and min element. For more information read pandas basic functionality docs.

Comment: can I use this list for sci-kit libraries  ?

Comment: Yeah, you can use them for scikit libraries. You can use the map function to do it for all columns.

Comment: if I use df[column_name] every time I need to specify column name
for example df[sepal length] , df[petal length], how can get the columns automatically one by one, do I need to use any for loops  or is there any other way?

Comment: df = pd.read_csv(url, names=names, usecols=['sepal length'])
print(df)
To find a particular column

Comment: use list(map(lambda x: list(df[x]),dataframe.columns)). This will give you a list of  column elements.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `describe`:

```
data.describe()
```

Output:

```
       sepal length  sepal width  petal length  petal width
count    150.000000   150.000000    150.000000   150.000000
mean       5.843333     3.054000      3.758667     1.198667
std        0.828066     0.433594      1.764420     0.763161
min        4.300000     2.000000      1.000000     0.100000
25%        5.100000     2.800000      1.600000     0.300000
50%        5.800000     3.000000      4.350000     1.300000
75%        6.400000     3.300000      5.100000     1.800000
max        7.900000     4.400000      6.900000     2.500000
```

Or a single column:

```
data['petal length'].describe()
```

Output:

```
count    150.000000
mean       3.758667
std        1.764420
min        1.000000
25%        1.600000
50%        4.350000
75%        5.100000
max        6.900000
Name: petal length, dtype: float64
```

Or you can use `apply` with lambda to do some custom processing by columns.

```
data.apply(lambda x: x.describe())
```

Output:

```
        sepal length  sepal width  petal length  petal width        class
25%         5.100000     2.800000      1.600000     0.300000          NaN
50%         5.800000     3.000000      4.350000     1.300000          NaN
75%         6.400000     3.300000      5.100000     1.800000          NaN
count     150.000000   150.000000    150.000000   150.000000          150
freq             NaN          NaN           NaN          NaN           50
max         7.900000     4.400000      6.900000     2.500000          NaN
mean        5.843333     3.054000      3.758667     1.198667          NaN
min         4.300000     2.000000      1.000000     0.100000          NaN
std         0.828066     0.433594      1.764420     0.763161          NaN
top              NaN          NaN           NaN          NaN  Iris-setosa
unique           NaN          NaN           NaN          NaN            3
```

Answer (score 0):

some dummy data

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'sepal length' : np.random.randn(3), 'sepal width' : np.random.randn(3)})
```

if you want some customize calculations on all the columns one by one then you can apply for loop on the column names as

```
>>>for col in data.columns:
            print(col)
            print(np.mean(data[col]))
[out]: 'sepal length'
        -1.06206436799
       'sepal width'
       -0.586939385059
```

If you are importing data in pandas dataframe then this would be the output.You can also include your customise operations on columns in the loop.

Comment: It is showing an error EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: Sorry was my mistake i should comment out the customize function string.Now its working fine on my machine.

Comment: I understand, i think the problem with data.columns

Comment: what is the type of data here? It should be pandas dataframe then data.column method will work on it which will give you the list of all columns.

Comment: the type of data is float for variables :sepal length', 'sepal width', 'petal length', 'petal width                                                                                             
For the variable class it is string type

Comment: I had edit the answer.Hope it will work for you this time.